# Image within LI class

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get my bullet-point.png images to show up on the right side of each of my navigation/li menu options.

I did it with some in-valid HTML5, but would prefer to do it properly. Here is my screenshot from before so it explains what I am after. (I previously just added in multiple  strings on each menu item). I think it's better to have each menu item assigned to a class with a background-image defined instead.

[image]

The HTML/CSS below displays the navigation like the screenshot but without any of the bullet-point images. Any idea why?

HTML

```
<nav class="nav">
                <div class="span12">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="bullet-point"><a href="#" class="active">HOME</a></li>
                        <li class="bullet-point"><a href="#">PROJECTS</a></li>
                        <li class="bullet-point"><a href="#">CASE STUDIES</a></li>
                        <li class="bullet-point"><a href="#">PROFILE</a></li>
                        <li class="bullet-point"><a href="#">NEWS &#38; EVENTS</a></li>
                        <li class="bullet-point"><a href="#">LOCATION</a></li>
                        <li class="bullet-point"><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
```

CSS

```
.bullet-point {
    margin-top: -5px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: url('img/bullet-point.png');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/avinvarghese/eemTZ/

Css:

```
    .bullet-point {
        margin-top: -5px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        list-style:none;
        float:left;
    }
    .bullet-point:after {
        content:" • ";
    }
    .bullet-point:last-child:after {
        content: "";
}
```

Comment: +1 @avin varghese but i have updated the fiddle so the last child dot wont appear http://jsfiddle.net/4jnZs/2/

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
ul {
   list-style-image: url('img/bullet-point.png');
}
```

Background images do not apply here.